# Fail exporting from Google Cloud SQL to GCS

Tags: sql, postgresql, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying make an export from a Postgresql at Google Cloud SQL to Google Cloud Storage, but I'm getting the following error:

```
failed to upload data to GCS URL gs://my-bucket/my-export-202101281350.csv: data.Seek(0, 0) error: seek to before memory to: 0 base: 3349304054
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/175937031), this was an on going issue and it is supposed that is fixed. However, it seems like some customers are still facing it.

I recommend you to run [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-pgdump.html) on your own against your instance (without using Cloud SQL export) so that you be able to export your Cloud SQL database.